# Python regex with multiple optional groups and varying lengths

Tags: python, regex

I have a variety of complex filenames that I need to match with a regex. This is the general pattern, optional groups in round brackets:

```
<main>_<country>-<region>(_<id>)(_<provider>)_<year><month><day>_<hour><minute><second>_<sensor>_<resolution>(_<bittype>).<format>
```

Here are some examples of what those filenames can look like:

```
fn1 = 'FOO_is-atest_123456_COMPANY_20190729_153343_SATEL_m0001_32bit.tif'
fn2 = 'FOO_is-atest_COMPANY_20190729_153343_SATEL_m0001_32bit.tif'
fn3 = 'FOO_is-atest_COMPANY_20190729_153343_SATEL_m0001.tif'
fn4 = 'FOO_is-atest_32tnt_20211125_120005_SATEL_m0001.tif'
fn5 = 'FOO_is-atest_20211125_120005_SATEL_cm070.tif'
fn6 = 'FOO_is-atest_20211125_120005_SATEL_cm070_32bit.tif'
```

The different components can have varying lengths sometimes. The tricky part is that `tile` and `provider` can basically consist of any given length and any character.

I just can't get it to match all the cases. Here is the closest I came, using [this nice online regex test page here](https://regex101.com/r/O8NniM/1):

```
import re

pattern = '(?P<product>\w{3})' \
          '_(?P<country>\w{2})' \
          '-(?P<region>\w+)' \
          '_?(?P<tile>\w+)?' \
          '_?(?P<provider>\w+)?' \
          '_(?P<year>\d{4})' \
          '(?P<month>\d{2})' \
          '(?P<day>\d{2})' \
          '_(?P<hour>\d{2})' \
          '(?P<minute>\d{2})' \
          '(?P<second>\d{2})' \
          '_(?P<sensor>\w{5})' \
          '_(?P<res_unit>km|m|cm)' \
          '(?P<resolution>\d{3,4})' \
          '_?(?P<bittype>\d{1,2}bit)?' \
          '.(?P<format>\w+)'

p = re.compile(pattern)

print(p.match(fn1).group('tile'), p.match(fn1).group('provider'))
print(p.match(fn2).group('provider'), p.match(fn2).group('bittype'))
print(p.match(fn3).group('provider'), p.match(fn3).group('resolution'))
print(p.match(fn4).group('tile'), p.match(fn4).group('year'))
print(p.match(fn5).group('provider'), p.match(fn5).group('resolution'))
print(p.match(fn6).group('provider'), p.match(fn5).group('bittype'))

# OUTPUTS:
>>> (None, None)
>>> (None, '32bit')
>>> (None, '0001')
>>> (None, '2021')
>>> (None, '070')
>>> (None, None)
```

As you see, `tile` and `provider` are not correctly recognized, so something it still not right. Everything else seems to work fine. Regexes are still somewhat of a mystery to me, to be honest.

Comment: I think it would at least become better if you replace `_?(?P<tile>\w+)?` by `(_(?P<tile>\w+))?`, same for "provider" because the underscore is not independently optional.

Comment: So from a regex point of view, if bothg provider and title are just one or more word chars, and only one of them exists. How is it meant to know if it should be the title or the provider. or is there a more specific format that can be used to identify one over the other

Comment: `tile` and `provider` are definitely separated by an underscore and always at the same position.

Comment: Whenever you use `\w`, mind that it also matches underscores. If you do not expect your "fields" to contain underscores, replace all `\w` with `[^\W_]`. Also, `_?(?P<name>[^\W_]+)?` is not a good way to match optional groups, use ``(?:_(?P<name>[^\W_]+))?`` instead.

Comment: if '_' is always used as a delimiter, `split()` is easier to read and probably faster.

Comment: In this line `fn4 = 'FOO_is-atest_32tnt_20211125_120005_SATEL_m0001.tif'` for the field `32tnt` is this title or provider? how is the regex meant to know?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, this is the `tile` and now that you mention it, this is indeed very hard know when there is no clear rule to it. The only workaround might be to force the `provider` to only contain characters, while the `tile` may have everything except for an underscore.

Comment: yes this is the point i was trying to make in my earlier comment. if there is no clear identifying structure between tile and provider and they are both optional then its impossible to say from a code perspective when only one exists, if its a provider or a tile.

Comment: Thanks for hinting at that, so I need to come up with a rule for these two. Thanks for all the comments, they really helped.
I think I need to restrict the `tile` and then it should work.

Comment: Do you need https://regex101.com/r/zwv03L/1 ?

Comment: As @ChrisDoyle pointed out, there is no rule to discriminate between `tile` and `provider`, otherwise your link would be the perfect solution. So I need to come up with such a rule and will then build on your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Then I think https://regex101.com/r/zwv03L/2 is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
^(?P<product>[^\W_]{3})_(?P<country>[^\W_]{2})-(?P<region>\w+?)(?:_(?P<tile>[^_]+))??(?:_(?P<provider>[^\W_]+))?_(?P<year>\d{4})(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<day>\d{2})_(?P<hour>\d{2})(?P<minute>\d{2})(?P<second>\d{2})_(?P<sensor>[^\W_]{5})_(?P<res_unit>km|m|cm)(?P<resolution>\d{3,4})(?:_(?P<bittype>\d{1,2}bit))?\.(?P<format>\w+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zwv03L/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<product>[^\W_]{3})` - Group "product": three alphanumeric chars
- `_` - an underscore
- `(?P<country>[^\W_]{2})` - Group "country": two alphanumeric chars
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?P<region>\w+?)` - Group "region": one or more alphanumeric or underscore chars, **as few as possible**
- `(?:_(?P<tile>[^_]+))??` - **an optional sequence of patterns that is matched only if the subsequent patterns in the regex fail to match (see lazy `??` quantifier)**:

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `(?P<tile>[^_]+)` - Group "title": one or more chars other than `_`
- `(?:_(?P<provider>[^\W_]+))?`
- `_(?P<year>\d{4})`
- `(?P<month>\d{2})` - Group "month": two digits
- `(?P<day>\d{2})` - Group "day": two digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `(?P<hour>\d{2})` - Group "hour": two digits
- `(?P<minute>\d{2})` - Group "minute": two digits
- `(?P<second>\d{2})` - Group "second": two digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `(?P<sensor>[^\W_]{5})` - Group "sensor": five alphanumeric chars
- `_` - an underscore
- `(?P<res_unit>km|m|cm)` - Group "res_unit": `km`, `m` or `cm` (also `[kc]m`
  can be used)
- `(?P<resolution>\d{3,4})` - Group "resolution": three or four digits
- `(?:_(?P<bittype>\d{1,2}bit))?` - an optional sequence of `_` and then Group "bittype" capturing one or two digits and then `bit` string
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?P<format>\w+)` - Group "format": one or more alphanumeric/underscore chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Almost... in the provided examples, example 4 contains `32tnt`, which is not the `provider`, but the `tile`. As others pointed out, the two cannot be differentiated without a specific rule. I need accept that and work around it in other ways, although I really appreciate your dedication to this question.

Comment: @s6hebern It is still usable. Get the group  "provider" and "title" with this regex. Then use SpaCy and convert both into SpaCy documents. Check the entities, if one of them is a company name, it is a `provider`. If you have a finite list of providers you may use a pattern like `provider1|provider2|etc`  instead of a generic pattern.